# how to show data via ajax in multiple rows of dynamic dropdowns fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[Here is the image view of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOqN0.jpg). I have a row of three dropdown fields, container, supplier and products that dynamic populate based on what the user selects. if select container name from first dropdown field then the supplier name will come in second dropdown field and after select supplier name then product name will show in third dropdown field. For my first row it's working fine. But after add second row dynamically it's not working.i have no idea how to solve this.

```
<script>

 var j=1;  
      $('#add1').click(function(){  
           j++;  
           `$('#dynamic_field1').append('<tr id="row1'+j+'"><td><?php $sql="select container_name FROM arrival_container ORDER BY id DESC";$result = $mysqli->query($sql);?><select class="form-control container" data-style="btn-light" name="container_name[]"  id="container1"><optgroup label="Container Name"><option value="">Select container</option><?php if($result->num_rows > 0){while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ echo '<option value="'.$row['container_name'].'">'.$row['container_name'].'</option>';}}else{echo'<option value="">Container not available</option>';}?></optgroup>`</select></td><td><select class="form-control"data-style="btn-light" name="supplier_name[]" id="supplier1"><optgroup label="Supplier Name"><option value="">Select container first</option></optgroup></select></td><td><select class="form-control" data-style="btn-light" name="product_name []"id="product1"><optgroup label="Product Name"><option value="">Select supplier first</option></optgroup></select></td><td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="unit_price[]" placeholder="Unit Price" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="comments[]" placeholder="Comments" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="hidden" name="order_id[]"value="<?php echo"$order_uidd";?>"placeholder="Enter taking time" class="form-control name_list"  /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+j+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove1">X</button></td></tr>'); 




$( "#container1" ).on( "change", function() {
            var container_Name = $(this).val();
    if(container_Name){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'container_name='+container_Name,
            success:function(html){
                $('#supplier1').html(html);
                $('#product1').html('<option value="">Select supplier first</option>'); 
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#supplier1').html('<option value="">Select container first</option>');
        $('#product1').html('<option value="">Select supplier first</option>'); 
    }

});




    $( "#supplier1" ).on( "change", function() {
            var supplier_Name = $(this).val();
            if(supplier_Name){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'ajaxData.php',
                    data:'supplier_name='+supplier_Name,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#product1').html(html);
                    }
                }); 
            }else{
                $('#product1').html('<option value="">Select supplier first</option>'); 
            }
        });



});



    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove1', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row1'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"../dyn-assets/medicine.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      }); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML. Do you mean that there are several rows, each one with a `#container1` element? An element's [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique to the document. If you are repeating them, consider using a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead.

Comment: i used class instead id but there have a problem also. When change second row container dropdown menu's value , first row dropdown value also changing. here is my code HTML code link : https://github.com/asif-uchchhas/myProblem